# I want to place the jQuery Tooltip in the upper right corner of the visible window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

Is there a way to do this with the jQuery tooltip?

If not, what is the best way to do this?

I will have up to 400 items on one page that will need a tooltip with an image and text. The tip must support HTML and not be text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, this is the basic syntax for setting the tooltip's position when first initializing it:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({
  position: { my: "right top", at: "right top", of: window }
});
```

If you need more specific details, please post your html and js.

Comment: Here is my code. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/oahure/ff9cc3kL/2/

It does not work on the first mouse over, but it works on each additional one. If you hit Run you will the first one always does not work.

Comment: Its working fine for me here.  http://jsfiddle.net/ff9cc3kL/3/  Keep in mind if the tooltip displays over the element you are hovering (i.e. it gets in between the cursor and the element) the cursor is at that instant no longer hovering over the element and the tooltip goes away.  You may not even see the tooltip, or it will just flash for a millisecond.  Also keep in mind that the jsfiddle "Result" is running in an iframe, which is interpreted by the browser as its own window.

Comment: You may want to consider positioning the tooltip relative to the cursor or the hoverable element, rather than the window.  That way the above situation is not able to happen.  I also calculate where the cursor is on the screen and position the tooltip on the right/left/top/bottom depending on the result so it does not get cut off by the edge of the window.